# How to do a mean and a max in the same time doing a groupby?

Tags: pandas-groupby

I have the same list of destinations (Italy, Greece, Spain,etc.) included in a list of airline companies (Easyjet, Panam, Ryan Air, etc.). 
Each of these destinations has a length.
Depending of the company, the same destination can have a different length so:
1. I want to find the mean of the destinations' length 
2. I want to find the 5 longest destinations

As a beginner in pandas, I'm wondering if there is a way to calculate this with a one and only groupby?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```py
df.groupby('Destination')
  .mean()
  .sort_values('Destination Length', ascending=False)
  .head(5)
```